# Jenkins Pipeline S3 Upload: missing file

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I'm in the process of migrating all our Jenkins jobs into pipelines and, using a JenkinsFile for better control (committed to CodeCommit, AWS' GIT).

One of the steps in our jobs is the Post Build Action that uploads files to S3, which works correctly in the Jenkins' jobs, but haven't been able to correctly replicate it in the JenkinsFile. I think I've tried every possible combination provided in the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin#s3upload) but, despite the process says that "worked", no file appears in S3 console.

Since our target file gets named based on version number extracted from pom.xml, I need to use wildcards to get it's name using the following syntax:

```
 s3Upload(bucket:"myBucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*.war', workingDir:'target')
```

The 'path/to/targetFolder/' gets created and the log shows:

```
Uploading
file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mailer%20pipeline/target/mailer%23%231.3.2.war to s3://myBucket/path/to/targetFolder/ 
Finished: Uploading to myBucket/path/to/targetFolder/
Upload complete
```

But no file gets into the target folder.

What could I be  missing?

Comment: You can debug by putting a lot of `sh 'ls -l /path/to/` steps in your pipeline to check if your file is really in the folder where you would expect it. I would also try to begin very easy. for example the includepathpattern with a real path that exisits or just *.war before trying subfolders.

Comment: @lvthillo  File actually is in the workspace, exactly where I expect it. A fix has already been provided. Please see answer just entered below

Comment: This is still happening to me with the most recent version of this plugin - especially when I nest it within a retry.  I switched to use the aws cli instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed an error in the plugin. I reported it to [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/issues/53) and a contributor released a fix.